# linking to static glib-2.0 libraries cross 32 and 64

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, linker, glib

To link to static glib-2.0 libraries using -m32 and -m64 for 32 and 64 bit executables/shared libraries.

I was installing libglib2.0-dev and libglib2.0-dev:i386.

When i install ibglib2.0-dev:i386, it removes the libglib2.0-dev, the amd64 package 
When i install ibglib2.0-dev:amd64, it removes the libglib2.0-dev:i386 package.

So, basically the the 32 and 64 bit version of static libglib-2.0 library could not co-exist and hence i am not able to compile 32 and 64 bit executable on same 64 bit linux machine.

Comment: Belongs on the SE site AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really belong on SO—it's an issue with the Ubuntu packaging, so it would fit better on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).  That said, I believe what you're looking for is [Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch).

Also, keep in mind that *statically* linking to glib has [license implications](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic) which you need to be mindful of.